# showing compactness of the intersection of a compact set and disjoint open sets.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Here's the problem I'm trying to solve.

"If $A\subseteq B_1\cup B_2$ where $B_1, B_2$ are disjoint open sets and $A$ is compact,     show that $A\cap B_1$ is compact. Is the same true if $B_1$ and $B_2$ are not disjoint?"

Hope you can help, I can't seem to wrap my head around this one. Thanks!

Comment: At this point, I've tried going down the road of using $A$ being closed and bounded, and I've been looking into why $B_1, B_2$ have to be disjoint and open. Unfortunately I've hit a brick wall.

Comment: Other people have posted good solutions, so I will just say this: showing a set is compact almost always begins by choosing an open cover. In this case, this is the right strategy because you already know that $A$ is compact, so the finiteness condition kicks in the moment you have an open cover of $A$. Once you've got those finitely many sets, you should have some intuition that they're involved with the finite open cover you're trying to find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\{V_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in J}$ be a family of open sets such that:
$$A\cap B_1\subseteq\cup_{\alpha\in J}V_{\alpha}$$Since $A\subseteq B_1\cup B_2$, it follows that $A\subseteq\ B_2\cup(\cup_{\alpha\in J}V_{\alpha})$. Since $A$ is compact , therefore there is a finite subset of $\{{V_{\alpha}}|\alpha\in J\}\cup\{B_2\}$ that covers $A$. Now try to use this subset (along with the fact that $B_1\cap B_2=\emptyset$) to make a finite subset of $\{{V_{\alpha}}|\alpha\in J\}$ that covers $A\cap B_1$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $\cal U$ be an open cover of $A\cap B_1$ then $\{U\cup B_2\mid U\in\cal U\}$ is an open cover of $A$.

For the second part note that $[0,1]\subseteq (-1,1)\cup(\frac12,\frac43)$.